# Best way to splice together 20/22 gauge wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring

We have some holiday lights that had wiring snipped it seems and wondering what others have done to permanently splice 22 gauge wiring (fed from 3.5V plug).

Update:  On one set I have soldered the two segments together via gas stove (yes this worked well and it is one unit unless I break out scissors.  Which I guess I will have to do since you need to put on the crimper or whatever connector.  Guess I can redo once one of these is already on one side since it has power unit on one end and street light on another.

Comment: The absolute best approach would be soldered & insulated with heat shrink tubing (or, failing that, electrical tape).  You can buy an electric soldering iron quite cheaply, or you may be able to find an old soldering copper you can heat in the stove.  The crimp connectors are not good on a cord that may be tugged, as they can pull loose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

3M Scotchlok's would work for this application.  They too would require a trip to a store, but the nice part is you don't need to strip the wire as they are self-piercing.  They can connect two or three wires, and are filled with a sealant to provide moisture resistance.

They are typically used for Telco wiring, but support wire gauge from 26-19AWG.

[image: Skotchlok]

Comment: Ohhh like that.  Never have seen one but never have looked for this.

Comment: These. They work, the sealant is good, and there's no kludging involved. They may only work correctly on **solid** wire, (since I've primarily used them for telephone wire, which is, it's never been an issue for my use.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal - The wires are solid.  However a search of big box websites shows nothing... Will see if I can find these in the electrical aisle.

Comment: If that fails, have the address of a real electrical supply in your back pocket - it's really surprising what you "simply can't buy" at despot/lowly some days (try finding schedule 80 PVC conduit, for instance)

Comment: Wondered what these were called... There are other flavors of self-piercing connectors, though I've more often seen those used on speaker cable/lamp cord than on smaller wires.

Comment: FWIW, I've never had an issue with these and stranded wire.  I have always picked these up from an electrical supply, but I was surprised to see them at home depot recently.

Answer (score 6):

I think @bib's suggestion of a crimp connector is the best way to go.  If it was a 120V line outside, you should use a heat shrink crimp connector, but for low voltage this is optional (but still a good idea to prevent corrosion).

[image]

The only other alternative I can think of that I'd consider is soldering the wires together, and sealing the connection in a piece of heat shrink tubing.

[image: soldering heat shrink]
[image: heat shrink splice]

---

Anything short of a crimped or soldered connection is not going to be reliable.

Anything that involves electrical tape is... well, at best, a temporary quick-fix. Even the best taping job looks like crap compared to other types of splices.

[image: not terrible-looking electrical tape splice] [image: wire nuts wrapped in electrical tape]

Comment: I already have one soldered together via gas stove... The crimp connector and the shrink tubing will not work now.  Since one end is connected to power and the other to the pretty miniature street light.

Answer (score 4):

Consider *[crimp connectors](http://www.radioshack.com/crimp-on-butt-connectors-10-pack/6403037.html#q=crimp%2Bconnector&start=1)*

[image: crimp connector]

While these are best used with a crimping tool, they can be set using a conventional or needlenose plier.

```
Images and links are for illustration only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.
```

Comment: How do I even get it down to bare wire?

Comment: Wirestripper. I often set mine to a gauge slightly larger than the actual, especially on finer wire.

Comment: I must have some crappy strippers because it either cuts the wires or just leaves a mark in them.  I feel this is a job for an elf.

Comment: I find that the pricier strippers, such as a [Klein](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Klein-Tools-Wire-Stripper-Cutter-with-Solid-and-Stranded-Wire-11054/203581434) is worth it. However elves use the Acme-Kris-Kringle Universal Thingamajig

Comment: Most cheap strippers are crappy. You want them set so they just barely avoid cutting the copper; that may leave a bit of plastic intact but it should be little enough that you can pull the insulation off the wire with a moderately light yank. Practice makes better. If you really can't make strippers work for you, you may find you're better off with a knife, either cutting around the insulation as the strippers do or just whittling it away from the wire. (I once had to strip a rather insanely thin wire inside surprisingly thick insulation; steady hand and a scalpel were the best solution.)

Comment: My elves use the $3 red harbor freight strippers.  I guess I will have to be very careful.  Any ideas beyond a crimp connector which will require a trip to big box?

Comment: @keshlam - I was thinking about a scalpel.  I haven't done a surgery in 10 years so might as well use my spare scalpel for something.

Comment: With a pair of good strippers, you can hold them on a bit of an angle to cut thinner wire -- but they need to be very sharp. Takes some practice to get good at it.

Comment: @gregmac - there is literally metal as thin as thread in there.  These might be very very short cords by the time I practice enough.

Comment: You also can simply twist and solder them and then wrap with electrical tape. That assumes you have a light duty soldering iron and electrical solder (another field trip?). You also can use tiny wire nuts (they make them for 22-24 gauge at least).

Comment: You might be able to melt the wire off but the fumes are dangerous to breath and it's actually hard to do without making a mess. A heat gun is probably the best way, but a small butane torch can work (or your soldering iron if you  don't care about it getting covered in burnt, melted plastic).

Comment: Got them off... used the gas range.  Will just keep them taped until I get a crimper or little nut.  Only big nuts here.

Comment: You really need to use the special-purpose pliers with most crimp connectors.  When using regular pliers the connection is quite unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, crimp connectors are the way to go. If they will be used outdoors, I suggest either putting some dielectric grease inside the butt connectors or using some kind of sealing heatshrink tubing around the connector to help prevent corrosion.

Comment: If you go crimp, you'll definitely need to seal them good.  I prefer to solder and heat shrink tube due to the number of corroded (to the point of failure) crimp connectors I've dealt with in cars (which are at least mostly shielded from the weather)...  However, one must be aware that solder joints are even more susceptible to damage from bending motion than crimp connectors...

Comment: Soldering is good if one can arrange the wires properly. However, they are susceptible to mechanical fatigue. Surprisingly, a good crimped joint is often more reliable.